# Magento2 checkout form: How to display placeholder attribute value in fields?

Tags: input, placeholder, magento2, onepage-checkout

Goodmorning Stackoverflow,

I'm customizing the checkout onepage in Magento 2. Now I'm trying to display placeholders instead of labels in the shipping-address form, but no success till now. I hope someone can help me out

Cheers, Jorge

UPDATE:

In the console i can see a variable is giving to the attribute placeholder of the element input.

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder, // <<<< right here
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" name="street[0]" placeholder="" aria-describedby="notice-BVWUCFN" id="BVWUCFN">
```

Now i would like to know if theres is a way to modify this variable via the backend, so i can display label name in the placeholder attr. 
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19zxi.png)

Apoligies for my bad english

Comment: You need to be more specific and show us some code of your attempts so we can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Standard way,**

Copy all html  files from ***`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/`***
at 
***`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element/`***

Then  change all Change `placeholder: placeholder` to `placeholder: label` as mention by  [Akis Verillis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5985410/akis-verillis).

**Now you need  to  deploy the static files  by below code:**

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And see the magic.

**Note:** *If you have checkout from github then try copy from*

```
/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Amit. I already did that. it works like a charm. I couldnt vote on your answer cause not enough earn-points

Comment: Can we remove the overlapping label field too? I wish I could meet and give the Front End Developer of Checkout on M2 some words...

Comment: how can we add different worl like label is 'name' and placeholder is 'insert your name'?

Answer (score 3):

Change `placeholder: placeholder` to `placeholder: label`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in Magneto 2 documentation now:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html
The templates are the ones mentioned in previous answers.
The templates from magento-ui module are used in other places than checkout.

In your custom module directory, create a new /view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file. In this file, add content similar to the following:

```html
...
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
<arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        ...
        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- the field you are customizing -->
                        <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">%Vendor_Module%/form/element/%your_template%</item>
```

`%Vendor_Module%/form/element/%your_template%`
path is [your theme dir]/Vendor_Module/web/template/form/element/your_template.html

Clear browser cache too beside:
Delete all files in the pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessing directories.

Comment: To customize billing address you need to extend Magneto/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php because in my version (2.1.5) all values are hardcoded. Hope this info will help you

Answer (score 1):

If this is useful for you, the definition of that element is in:
*`/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html`*
It defines an input as:

```
<input
class="admin__control-text"
type="text"
data-bind="
    value: value,
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `placeholder` item to a layout.xml file for your field. Just like this:

```
<item name="address" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">contactForm</item>
   <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
   <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
</item>
<item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">Address</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">address</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Address</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
```